# MongoDB Compass - I have multiple collections in a single database, how to export all collections into one .csv file

Tags: mongodb

I am able to export single collection into a .csv file. I have a database, have multiple collections, want to export all collections into one .csv file. 
Could you please help me how to do the same.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for you.
you can use this

Use mongoexport to export the data:

```
mongoexport --db test --collection traffic --out traffic.json
```

execute the command in mongo command shell

if still have a problem then please refer [this official stuff](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#bin.mongoexport)

Comment: it works for one collection, I have multiple collections names in a database. I tried --collection * it did not worked.

Comment: then i sugest to use 3T studio ir robo 3t to better GUI experiance with mongo that studio provide you features what you expect actually